# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.modeling_roberta'

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, nlp-question-answering

I'm trying to run this project in github: https://github.com/dr-majie/WSTQ
and unfortunatly getting no respone on the issue I've created from the writers.

I tryied to run it using creating an anaconda environment with the latest versions of transformes and torch but got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.modeling_roberta'
```

So, I created another environment with the dependencies specified on the project but got another error:
tokenizers      0.10.3
pytorch         1.5.0
transformers    4.11.3

```
RuntimeError: cublas runtime error : the GPU program failed to execute at
```

I have already finished the training part of the project and had the checkpoints on my drive.
I find it strange that the training does not encounter any problems and only when I test the model I get the errors that I specified before.

Any help?